# Advice need for React Navigation auth flow structure

Tags: firebase, react-native, structure, react-navigation

Trying out react navigation v5 so I created a login register form that brings the user to the dashboard if he's logged in before using AsyncStorage. It works fine but I would like to know how to improve on the structure of code. Currently, I put all the components in a stack navigator, but things might get messy if I were to add more screens. Also, I would be switching to hooks but am confused if and how I should apply useContext useMemo useEffect

App.js file

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import Login from './components/login';
import Signup from './components/signup';
import Dashboard from './components/dashboard';
import AuthLoading from './components/authLoading'

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="AuthLoading"
      screenOptions={{
        headerTitleAlign: 'center',
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#3740FE',
        },
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
        },
      }}>
        <Stack.Screen
       name="AuthLoading"
       component={AuthLoading}
       options={
         {title: 'AuthLoading'},
         {headerLeft:null}
       }/>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Signup"
        component={Signup}
        options={{ title: 'Signup' }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Login"
        component={Login}
        options={
          { title: 'Login' },
          { headerLeft: null }
        }
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Dashboard"
        component={Dashboard}
        options={
          { title: 'Dashboard' },
          { headerLeft: null }
        }
      />

    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyStack />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

authLoading.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, StatusBar, StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native'

export default class AuthLoadingScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.checkUserToken();
  }

  async checkUserToken() {
    const isLoggedIn = await AsyncStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn');
    console.log(isLoggedIn)
    // If User Token
    if (isLoggedIn === '1') {
      //AsyncStorage.setItem(isLoggedIn);
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard');

    }
    else {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
    }
  }

  // Render any loading content that you like here
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Checking Authentication</Text>
        <ActivityIndicator />
        <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}


// Styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#CA3433',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '500',
  },
});
```

signup.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button, Alert, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import firebase from '../database/firebase';


export default class Signup extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            displayName: '',
            email: '',
            password: '',
            isLoading: false
        }
    }

    updateInputVal = (val, prop) => {
        const state = this.state;
        state[prop] = val;
        this.setState(state);
    }

    registerUser = () => {
        if (this.state.email === '' && this.state.password === '') {
            Alert.alert('Enter details to signup!')
        } else {
            this.setState({
                isLoading: true,
            })
            firebase
                .auth()
                .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
                .then((res) => {
                    res.user.updateProfile({
                        displayName: this.state.displayName
                    })
                    console.log('User registered successfully!')
                    this.setState({
                        isLoading: false,
                        displayName: '',
                        email: '',
                        password: ''
                    })
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')
                })
                .catch(error => this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    errorMessage: error.message
                }))
        }
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.isLoading) {
            return (
                <View style={styles.preloader}>
                    <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#9E9E9E" />
                </View>
            )
        }
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.inputStyle}
                    placeholder="Name"
                    value={this.state.displayName}
                    onChangeText={(val) => this.updateInputVal(val, 'displayName')}
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.inputStyle}
                    placeholder="Email"
                    value={this.state.email}
                    onChangeText={(val) => this.updateInputVal(val, 'email')}
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.inputStyle}
                    placeholder="Password"
                    value={this.state.password}
                    onChangeText={(val) => this.updateInputVal(val, 'password')}
                    maxLength={15}
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                />
                <Button
                    color="#3740FE"
                    title="Signup"
                    onPress={() => this.registerUser()}
                />

                <Text>{this.state.errorMessage}</Text>

                <Text
                    style={styles.loginText}
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')}>
                    Already Registered? Click here to login
        </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        justifyContent: "center",
        padding: 35,
        backgroundColor: '#fff'
    },
    inputStyle: {
        width: '100%',
        marginBottom: 15,
        paddingBottom: 15,
        alignSelf: "center",
        borderColor: "#ccc",
        borderBottomWidth: 1
    },
    loginText: {
        color: '#3740FE',
        marginTop: 25,
        textAlign: 'center'
    },
    preloader: {
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        position: 'absolute',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#fff'
    }
});
```

login.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button, Alert, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import firebase from '../database/firebase';
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';


export default class Login extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            isLoading: false,
            errorMessage: ''
        }
    }

    updateInputVal = (val, prop) => {
        const state = this.state;
        state[prop] = val;
        this.setState(state);
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    userLogin = () => {
        if (this.state.email === '' && this.state.password === '') {
            this.setState({
                errorMessage: "Enter details to sign in"
            })
            //Alert.alert('Enter details to signin!')
        } else {
            this.setState({
                isLoading: true,
            })
            firebase
                .auth()
                .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
                .then((res) => {

                    console.log(res)
                    console.log('User logged-in successfully!')
                    this.setState({
                        isLoading: false,
                        email: '',
                        password: ''
                    })
                    AsyncStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', '1')
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard')
                })
                .catch(error => this.setState({
                    errorMessage: 'Wrong email/password',
                    isLoading: false
                }))
        }
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.isLoading) {
            return (
                <View style={styles.preloader}>
                    <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#9E9E9E" />
                </View>
            )
        }
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.inputStyle}
                    placeholder="Email"
                    value={this.state.email}
                    onChangeText={(val) => this.updateInputVal(val, 'email')}
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.inputStyle}
                    placeholder="Password"
                    value={this.state.password}
                    onChangeText={(val) => this.updateInputVal(val, 'password')}
                    maxLength={15}
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                />
                <Button
                    color="#3740FE"
                    title="Signin"
                    onPress={() => this.userLogin()}
                />
                {/* style this */}
                <Text>{this.state.errorMessage}</Text>

                <Text
                    style={styles.loginText}
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Signup')}>
                    Don't have account? Click here to signup
        </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        justifyContent: "center",
        padding: 35,
        backgroundColor: '#fff'
    },
    inputStyle: {
        width: '100%',
        marginBottom: 15,
        paddingBottom: 15,
        alignSelf: "center",
        borderColor: "#ccc",
        borderBottomWidth: 1
    },
    loginText: {
        color: '#3740FE',
        marginTop: 25,
        textAlign: 'center'
    },
    preloader: {
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        position: 'absolute',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#fff'
    }
});
```

dashboard.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button, Alert, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import firebase from '../database/firebase';
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';


export default class Login extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            isLoading: false,
            errorMessage: ''
        }
    }

    updateInputVal = (val, prop) => {
        const state = this.state;
        state[prop] = val;
        this.setState(state);
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    userLogin = () => {
        if (this.state.email === '' && this.state.password === '') {
            this.setState({
                errorMessage: "Enter details to sign in"
            })
            //Alert.alert('Enter details to signin!')
        } else {
            this.setState({
                isLoading: true,
            })
            firebase
                .auth()
                .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
                .then((res) => {

                    console.log(res)
                    console.log('User logged-in successfully!')
                    this.setState({
                        isLoading: false,
                        email: '',
                        password: ''
                    })
                    AsyncStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', '1')
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard')
                })
                .catch(error => this.setState({
                    errorMessage: 'Wrong email/password',
                    isLoading: false
                }))
        }
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.isLoading) {
            return (
                <View style={styles.preloader}>
                    <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#9E9E9E" />
                </View>
            )
        }
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.inputStyle}
                    placeholder="Email"
                    value={this.state.email}
                    onChangeText={(val) => this.updateInputVal(val, 'email')}
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.inputStyle}
                    placeholder="Password"
                    value={this.state.password}
                    onChangeText={(val) => this.updateInputVal(val, 'password')}
                    maxLength={15}
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                />
                <Button
                    color="#3740FE"
                    title="Signin"
                    onPress={() => this.userLogin()}
                />
                {/* style this */}
                <Text>{this.state.errorMessage}</Text>

                <Text
                    style={styles.loginText}
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Signup')}>
                    Don't have account? Click here to signup
        </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        justifyContent: "center",
        padding: 35,
        backgroundColor: '#fff'
    },
    inputStyle: {
        width: '100%',
        marginBottom: 15,
        paddingBottom: 15,
        alignSelf: "center",
        borderColor: "#ccc",
        borderBottomWidth: 1
    },
    loginText: {
        color: '#3740FE',
        marginTop: 25,
        textAlign: 'center'
    },
    preloader: {
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        position: 'absolute',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#fff'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React-Navigation provided help regarding the auth flow on their official site. Just follow the below link

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/

**Note:** You can follow this article for authentication flow using hooks and react-navigation 5

https://dev.to/embeddednature/create-an-authorization-flow-with-react-navigation-5-x-2pkh